# Extract Month and year in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to extract the month and year in SQL Server. For example if the date is 2015-01-01, I want to make it 201501  and convert it to varchar(6)

How do I do this?

Comment: Try this: `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), CAST('2015-01-01' AS DATE),112)`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please search first before asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

```
1. SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(6), GETDATE(), 112)

2. SELECT  CAST(YEAR(GETDATE()) * 100 + MONTH(GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(6))
```

Comment: this one is different and smart :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(yyyy, @date) * 100 + DATEPART(mm, @date)
```

If you want to do the operation on the current time then replace `@date` with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

The result is integer though, you may convert it to `varchar(6)` using `CAST()` or `CONVERT()` method.

Answer (score 1):

Try.. [FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/991c7/50)

```
declare @dt datetime='2015-01-01'
select CAST(YEAR(@dt)as Varchar(6))+
Case When Len(Cast(MONTH(@dt) as varchar(6)))>1 
then CAST(MONTH(@dt) as varchar(6)) Else 
'0'+Cast(MONTH(@dt) as varchar(6)) End
```

EDIT:2

```
declare @dt date='2015-01-01' 
select CAST(REPLACE(@dt,'-','')as varchar(6))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest answer

```
select getdate() , convert( varchar(6) , getdate() ,112)
```

and if you want year as 2 digit

```
select getdate() , convert( varchar(12) , getdate() ,12)
```

Whenever you want to convert date format from standard format to another format, always check this link.

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_convert.asp

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
select CONVERT(nvarchar(6), 
DATENAME(yyyy, getdate())) + 
SUBSTRING(CONVERT(nvarchar(6),getdate(), 112),5,2)
```

**DATENAME:**

Returns a character string that represents the specified datepart of the specified date

**ref:**

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms174395.aspx

for all datetime conversion this will help

http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/

Comment: not gonna work. Expected result is `201501`

Comment: @user3540365 Please see updated answer getting 201503